# Error when loading javascript libraries

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when loading the following javascript libraries.

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Failed to load resource (22:09:18:125 | error, network)
at http://localhost:8383/HTML5WebApp/js/libs/jquery-1.8.3/jquery.min.js
Failed to load resource (22:09:18:172 | error, network)
at http://localhost:8383/HTML5WebApp/js/libs/jqueryui-1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js
```

I am developing a HTML5 App, my src for the libraries I want for my App inside head tags:

```
<title>HTML5 WebApp</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jqueryui-1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Using Netbeans IDE With Chrome Extension.

Comment: What happens if you try to access those links, like http://localhost:8383/HTML5WebApp/js/libs/jquery-1.8.3/jquery.min.js , with a browser directly? Are you sure the file exists where you think it does?

Comment: I would recommend using the Chrome developer tools & analyzing the network tab for a bit more insight here

Comment: The problem is definitely in your project directory structure and what folders you've set up to be publicly accessible. Are you runnning any kind of web server? What does your back end look like

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the javascript files jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js are in the correct path as specified in head tags :js/libs/jquery-1.8.3/jquery.min.js and js/libs/jqueryui-1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this

1. [Download JS Library on here](https://jquery.com/download/)
2. `<script src="file_name.js"></script>//ex <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

some times this may occur when you seems offline on your browser(No Internet Connection)